# OData query to get all record fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dynamics-crm-2011, odata

I'm trying to get all record fields and create oData query and got some responseTxt

```
"d" : {
"results": [
"statuscode": {
"__metadata": {
"type": "Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.Data.Services.OptionSetValue"
}, "Value": 1
}
```

etc

I checked that all fields with their values present in responseText and then I got array

```
var GetVal = JSON.parse(this.responseText).d;
```

Now I need to take all fields names in

```
GetVal.results[0]
```

Because I can get value of some field, for example

```
GetVal.results[0]["new_name"]
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [iterating through json object javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323699/iterating-through-json-object-javascript)

Comment: Shanks, Thank you for answer! I already find solution