# How to get all dates listed in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, date, coldfusion

I'm trying to output all dates from start to end date to array. Once I get all dates in array I have created a function that loop thorough array and add a className. Here is my code that creates array:

```
<cfoutput query="qryOne">
    <cfloop from="#PickDateTime#" to="#DropDateTime#" index="i" step="#CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0)#">
        dateArray[#currentrow#] = new Array("#UserID#","#dateformat(i,'mmddyyyy')#");
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

and here is my JavaScript function:

```
var dateArray = new Array();

function getDate(){
    for (var i=1; i < dateArray.length; i++){
        result = document.getElementById(dateArray[i][1])
        result.className = 'booked'
    }
}
```

So problem that I have at this point is that code gives me just End dates. Sometimes I have 
start and end time that happen on the same date but also sometimes we can have date range. Here is few examples:

```
Start           End
01/21/2015    01/21/2015
08:00 AM      12:30 PM
01/23/2015    01/24/2015
09:00 AM      03:00 PM
01/31/2015    02/05/2015
11:00 AM      10:00 AM
```

So my current code gives me just the end dates, I need to get all dates. If anyone see what I'm doing wrong in my code above please let me know. Thanks.

Comment: You are only storing a single date in the JS array, see:  `dateArray[#currentrow#] = new Array("#UserID#","#dateformat(i,'mmddyyyy')#");`

Comment: need to improve your query and loop to provide more data. Seems you are only creating an array of one of those date types in the query

Comment: To include more data in the array or?

Comment: Yes...definitely. Shoot for something in json like `[{"start":"...", "end":"..","id":".."},{"start":"...", "end":"..","id":".."}]`

Comment: In your ColdFusion Code you are creating new arrays inside a loop. Is that your intent?

Comment: I want to populate array with records from the coldfusion cfloop.

Comment: How this cfloop can be done with javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1769733/alex) and [charlietfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1175966/charlietfl) suggested, you array creation logic seems wrong. I assume you are trying to store the date range per user. In this case the, instead of array you should use structure for storing date arrays per user.

Apart from this I would suggest creating ColdFusion structure of date arrays first and then serializing it to JSON using ColdFusion's `SerializeJSON()` function.
Like this:

```
<cfset dateStruct = structNew() />
<cfoutput query="qryOne">
    <cfset dateStruct[userID] = arrayNew(1) />
    <cfloop from="#PickDateTime#" to="#DropDateTime#" index="i" step="#CreateTimeSpan(1,0,0,0)#">
        <cfset arrayAppend(dateStruct[userID],"#dateformat(i,'mmddyyyy')#")/>
    </cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

And then you can save the structure in JSON form in JavaScript variable using  function like this:

```
<script>
     var jsonString =  '<cfoutput>#SerializeJSON(dateStruct)#</cfoutput>';
     var JSONObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
</script>
```

Once you have JSON object in JavaScript, you can do whatever you need, using it.
If you want to loop over JSON object read this:
[iterating through json object javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323699/iterating-through-json-object-javascript)

Comment: I tried to implement JSONObject in function that I have above and I could not get to work. I used for loop to loop through JSON and then grab the key and assign the class name. How I can grab the value together with the key?

Comment: @user3023588 - Descriptions are ambiguous ;-) Instead of describing the code you used, please just post it. If possible, post a *stand alone example* others can run outside your environment. Generally, the easier it is for others to test the code, the more quickly you will get an answer.

Comment: Still struggling to create working example here, I will try to fix that. Thanks for advice.

Comment: How I can expand number of elements in my dateStruct, on date that is already there to add more elements from the query?