# How to parse a string in javascript to return something

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm making a bot in JavaScript for discord and one of it's commands will be custom commands that can give roles,

so I have a string from this: "{role:ROLE NAME}" and I would like to parse "ROLE NAME" out of this, I've looked into RegEx but I'm a little bit stuck

I was wondering if anyone has any suggestions, Thanks

EDIT: Just to say the { is just a symbol not JSON, it could be % or £

Comment: Please post the pattern you are stuck with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iterating through json object javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323699/iterating-through-json-object-javascript)

Comment: @dave it's not a JSON object though, the symbol could change to something like %role: Role name%

Comment: Why you dont use split?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I don't have one thats why I was asking for help.

Comment: You can use JSON.parse()

Comment: @MaherFattouh it's not JSON

Comment: That symbol could change

Answer (score 1):

You could parse out "ROLE NAME" with this regexp: `/:(.*?)\W$/`. Or you could parse it with `String#split` and `String#slice` like this: `s.split(":")[1].slice(0, -1)`.

[Working codepen](http://codepen.io/FullR/pen/XpgeVV)

Comment: @JosephBanks I should note that the regexp won't work if "}" appears in the role name. The split method should work with any pair as long as the key "role" doesn't contain ":".

Comment: Thanks I'll doubt anyone would put } in a role name but I'll try fix anyway

Comment: I also edited it to assume the end of the string could be any non-word character (such as % or £).