# How to extract some data from json in react JS (axios)?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, axios

I'm a ReactJS and axios newbie.

I want to iterate and extract json data if the key is number (like 0, 1, 2....)
and don't know how can I write this piece of code.
(because the server provide the json dynamically, and we don't know how many elements it will have)

Now I can extract the data with key = 0 (assume there exists this element)

```
class ContentBody extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            jdata: []
        }
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        var self = this;
        // read data periodically
        setInterval(function() {
            axios.get(URL)
                .then(function(response) {
                    self.setState({
                        jdata: response.data[0].Name
                    });
                })
                .catch(function(e) {
                    console.log("ERROR ", e);
                })
        }, 1000);
    }
}

// below is json data from the server
{
  "0": {
    "Assigned": false, 
    "Name": "BebopDrone-Test001.", 
    "droneID": 0
  }, 
  "1": {
    "Assigned": false, 
    "Name": "BebopDrone-B046836", 
    "droneID": 1
  }, 
  "2": {
    "Assigned": false, 
    "Name": "BebopDrone-Test002.", 
    "droneID": 2
  }, 
  "function": "getAllDroneStatus()"
}


// my pseudo code might be 
for(int i = 0; i < jsonObject.size(); i++){
    if(key is number){
        extract corresponding value
    }
 }
```

Comment: please put some codes

Comment: You can use `for..in` loop to iterate in the object.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323734/1619213

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response that you get from the server is an object, what you should do is loop over the Object and then update data in state where I assume you only need name

```
componentDidMount() {
    var self = this;
    // read data periodically
    setInterval(function() {
        axios.get(URL)
            .then(function(response) {
                var names=[];
                Object.keys(response.data).forEach(function(data) {
                     names.push(data.Name);
                })
                self.setState({
                    jdata: names
                });
            })
            .catch(function(e) {
                console.log("ERROR ", e);
            })
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: it's also a great way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your response is an Object not an Array.

You can't access an object using array indexing.

Assuming *response.data* is the body of your json, you should access your object properties like this: **response.data['0']**, **response.data['1']**, **response.data['2']**

You can iterate over an object using [for..in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

Your data model (aside from the reference to 'getAllDroneStatus()') suggests that an array might be more useful.

```
{
   "jdata" : [
      {
         "Assigned": false, 
         "Name": "BebopDrone-Test001.", 
         "droneID": 0
      }
    // ... 
    ]
}
```

Then you can iterate, reduce, filter and so on.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try.