# How to escape $ while inserting inside mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, koa

I have a large object which I have no control over, fields might vary a lot:

> Error ==>> { MongoError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$' in
>   'value.external.originalRequest.rawRequest.ns2:LoadData.Orders.0.Order.0.TotalThirdPartyCharge.0.CurrencyValue.0.$'
>   is not valid for storage. 0|lt-check |     at
>   Function.MongoError.create
>   (/home/ops/lt-checkin-api/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/error.js:31:11)
>   0|lt-check |     at
>   /home/ops/lt-checkin-api/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:497:72
>   0|lt-check |     at authenticateStragglers
>   (/home/ops/lt-checkin-api/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:443:16)
>   0|lt-check |     at Connection.messageHandler
>   (/home/ops/lt-checkin-api/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:477:5)
>   0|lt-check |     at Socket.
>   (/home/ops/lt-checkin-api/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:333:22)
>   0|lt-check |     at Socket.emit (events.js:159:13) 0|lt-check |     at
>   addChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:12) 0|lt-check |     at
>   readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:252:11) 0|lt-check |     at
>   Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10) 0|lt-check |     at
>   TCP.onread (net.js:608:20) 0|lt-check |   name: 'MongoError',
>   0|lt-check |   message: 'The dollar ($) prefixed field \'$\' in
>   \'value.external.originalRequest.rawRequest.ns2:LoadData.Orders.0.Order.0.TotalThirdPartyCharge.0.CurrencyValue.0.$\'
>   is not valid for storage.', 0|lt-check |   ok: 0, 0|lt-check |
>   errmsg: 'The dollar ($) prefixed field \'$\' in
>   \'value.external.originalRequest.rawRequest.ns2:LoadData.Orders.0.Order.0.TotalThirdPartyCharge.0.CurrencyValue.0.$\'
>   is not valid for storage.', 0|lt-check |   code: 52, 0|lt-check |
>   codeName: 'DollarPrefixedFieldName' }

Here the key causing the error:

```
"rawRequest": {
                        "ns2:LoadData": {
                            "$": {
                                "xmlns:ns2": "http://schemas.3gtms.com/tms/v1/tns"
                            },
                            "BatchInfo": [
                                {
                                    "$": {
                                        "xmlns": ""
                                    },
```

As there are multiple keys starting with $.

Is there a setting in mongoose or mongoDB itself to insert anything without validating the request coming in.

Comment: Why can't you do it in node before inserting into mongo?

Comment: I am not sure about the keys and moreover is there a good method to escape all the keys having $. @AnirudhSimha

Comment: check https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/ for reserved keywords.If it is a linux env its /\. "$

Comment: Was just looking around and found this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-escape

Comment: Great let me check if it helps

Comment: Escaping is a hack, fix the real problem - don't allow '$'

Comment: No doubt, but how can you restrict $ from some third party API then all you can do is escape @Adam

Comment: @BlackMamba - do you need to be stored in mongo as a document like this? Maybe you just need to store it stringified and then just parse it whenever you need to? Maybe not, just curious. `$` in keys in mongo are for specific purposes, and, in this document, you aren't using them for that, which is what makes me believe you'd be completely fine with just storing the stringified version of it.

Comment: It was long time ago I've answered with what I used back then. But that resolved the issue so all good for me

Comment: @BlackMamba - somehow this thread floated to the top of SO for me - I had no idea you had resolved this issue so long ago, my apologies!

Comment: NP this happens when there is some activity in any question like someone else answered @Adam

Answer (score 0):

Was going to create a new plugin but @Anirudh helped me find this package in the comment

https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongo-escape

To use it, just before your insert query escape you object using the above package.

```
var escapeForMongo = require('mongo-escape').escape;
userInput = escapeForMongo({
  'foo': 'bar',
  'ba.z': {
    '$in': 'quz'
  }
})
```

Comment: this library replaces all the dollars($) in keys and data with escaped characters. We just need to escape keys with dollar prefix in json.

Comment: No idea bud but I think if that's the case then you can iterate using `Object.keys(yourObject).map(i => newObject[i.replace(/^\$/)] = yourObject[i];)`
Not sure if it'll work just wrote without testing you can have something like this

Comment: Object.keys won't work for nested keys like your example above.

Comment: Hmm it's gonna be something iterative. I'll see either I can find some

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19323734/6517383 You can use this @BharatDBhadresha

Answer (score 0):

```js
function escapeMongo(obj) {
    return JSON.parse(
        JSON.stringify(obj),
        function(p, v) {
            if ((p[0] === '$') || (p.includes('.'))) {
                this[p.replace(/\$/g, '\uFF04').replace(/\./g, '\uFF0E')] = v;
                return;
            }
            return v;
        }
    )
}

userInput = {
    'foo': 'bar',
    'ba.z': {
        '$in': 'quz'
    }
}
console.log(userInput)
console.log(escapeMongo(userInput))
```

You can use JSON.parse to process a JSON string before creating object.